# JQ how to join array in one line?

Tags: jq

I have json file:

```
 [ 
 {
 "query": {
 "key1": "value1",
 "key2": "value2"
 }
 }
 ]
```

Need to join this array with one line so output will be:

```
key1=value1&key2=value2
```

I can join it values:

```
jq '.[].query | join("&")'
"value1&value2"
```

Or

Get key value string:

```
jq '.[].query | to_entries[] | "\(.key)=\(.value)"'
"key1=value1"
"key2=value2"
```

But how to concatenate this?
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this jq script:

```
<file jq -r '.[].query|to_entries|map([.key,.value]|join("="))|join("&")'
```

This joins twice the array containing the keys and values with `=` and `&` characters.